# Is there a break statement in Mule <foreach>

Tags: mule

I have an `array list` values which I loop using `<foreach>` and `<choice>`. As soon as the first hit happens in `choice` I want to come out of the `foreach` loop. Is there a way to `break` the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` may look like a procedural construct but behind the scene it uses a standard message splitter so it actually produces a bunch of messages out of the original collection.

So there is no mean to break anything: filtering with a `choice` or `filter` is the way to go.

Comment: In my case, I've a bunch of `ids` in array list and an another set of static values. I want to FTP my payload for the first match of id to pool of static values. I could have used filter if it would have been single value instead of array list.

Comment: Why don't you use an expression component to first perform the match? Better to use a real programming language like MEL than attempting _programming in XML_.