# MuleESB. How to stop for each loop?

Tags: json, foreach, mule, anypoint-studio

Good day, collagues.
Give me the cue, pls.
In one my case for JSON parsing i am using FOR EACH component with Choice inside him.
Like this: 
[image]

After http request i have in the paylaod some JSON result, which represents of some collection. Foreach treats every item from collection and compute it's properties with condition in Choice component.

I want to stop the loop when condition in Choice was found. I don't want to compare all items of result collection.

I tried to change the variable 'counter' inside the Fore each loop. But it is not working.

May be anybody has found the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not be able to do this using a for-each. But you could always have an expression/groovy script to do this loop and breaking based on your condition. Please refer this: [Is there a break statement in Mule <foreach>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336645/is-there-a-break-statement-in-mule-foreach)

Comment: This is really easy to parse JSON/HashMap with groovy.
I had read groovy syntax, and had realized the searching of some value in HashMap by groovy script.

Comment: Thank's)
But, i met another issue - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616714/groovy-transformer-was-like-ignored
The learning is the array of the mistakes)