# Groovy transformer was like ignored

Tags: json, groovy, hashmap, mule

Good day, collegues.
In my project i met some problem.
In one of flows i have made two http_requests and then have parsed those responses with groovy transformer.
[image]

First groovy script:

[image]

Second groovy script:
[image]

The first groovy script works fine. But the second script don't do anything. Like it was ignored.

Both http_responses's structures are similar.

Why the second groovy script can have been ignored?

Comment: your loops are running only once. is this by design?

Comment: Yes. After http_request hashmap has the collection, from wich i need to recieve only one item.

Comment: Would you post a sample result of your http request?

Comment: Begin of array "Result":
https://gyazo.com/b7d007187d7985bb1a4635c158769dc3

End of array "Result":
https://gyazo.com/be65d348f2a82936d256fc9d4720e8c5

Comment: {"NextPageExists":true,"Result":[{"SharedUsersExists":true,"Id":"c5cfce5c-7bc9-e511-80bd-e0cb4ef9c44d","Name":"! folder WATER )"},{"SharedUsersExists":true,"Id":"bea6a1c1-72d4-e511-80be-e0cb4ef9c44d","Name":"! for type"},{"SharedUsersExists":true,"Id":"0318d19e-4647-e611-80c0-e0cb4ef9c44d","Name":"! kosmos"},{"SharedUsersExists":true,"Id":"58c0a03c-dd18-e611-80bf-e0cb4ef9c44d","Name":"!!!000newFolder"}],"Page":1,"PageSize":20,"Count":20,"Error":"","IsSuccess":true,"Errors":[],"ValidationErrors":[],"ValidationWarnings":[]}

Comment: The script does work for me with your payload. What do you get if you put a logger before and after the groovy transformer? By the way, I do not see that value you are searching for in the result response (!!! a nanka) could it be that?

Comment: I had to make sample shorter then the original.
The value '!!! а папка' is there...
And if it wasn't, then "assert" should show this  - becouse [assert v.Id != null] will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg!(
I am very sorry, this was my very stupid mistake.
The reason is - 'break' must be in IF scope...
In the first http_response sought value is the first item in collection, that's why it works.

p.s. shame...