# How can I stop <foreach> loop in between in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I have an array list values which I loop using foreach and choice. As soon as the first success happens in choice I want to come out of the foreach loop. And I don't want continue to check remaining conditions. In mulesoft flow

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be able "break" foreach loop, but you can always achieve this functionality using expression/groovy script. Please refer this: [Is there a break statement in Mule <foreach>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336645/is-there-a-break-statement-in-mule-foreach)

Comment: Groovy is what I was going to suggest, however, could you expand on this answer? It doesn't provide a real working solution for the OP to use. Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Break Statement for exit from foreach loop according to your condition true.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr Raju Mali. In java it is working fine, but I want solution in "Mulesoft".

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your use case 
Wrap the `message filter` inside your `for-loop`.

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[]">
    <message-filter onUnaccepted="flow" >
        <expression-filter expression="#[]"/>
    </message-filter>
</foreach>
```

Comment: Thank you vijay for your response
just now I tried your suggestion like this 
------- <message-filter onUnaccepted="sampleflowFlow" doc:name="Message">
                <expression-filter expression="#[flowVars.a1=='true']"/>
            </message-filter>------
but in this scenario it is redirecting the starting point of the flow and it throws an exception because my input is xml after this operation I got json message-filter is try to give json as a input to my flow. I want to break for loop only need not to redirect whole flow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should find out on which index you will get success message by using indexOf method. Then after use subList method to get the required list and use that list in Foreach loop.

```
 <foreach collection="#[payload.subList(0,3)]" doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the OP wants to find the matching row **within** the for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Use [Groovy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/groovy-component-reference)**

You can control the flow of a Groovy script much easier than a traditional "for-each" transformer. In your particular case, your groovy script would look something (but not exactly) like:

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
 <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[// Define the collection to loop
    def loopCollection = flowVars.nameOfCollectiontoLoop

    // Define the condition which needs to be met
    def exitCondition = "Some condition to match"

    // Loop the collection to do what you need
    loopCollection.each { row ->
        if (row.identifierName == exitCondition)
        {
            return
        }
        else
        {
            // Continue your processing
        }   
    }

    return payload]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

**Use a [Choice](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/choice-flow-control-reference) strategy to stop processing**

The other way which I can think of is to use a [Choice](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/choice-flow-control-reference) as soon as you enter the loop to see if the condition has been previously met, if so, do nothing; as follows:

```
<flow name="testsFlow">
        <set-variable variableName="conditionMet" value="#[false]" doc:name="conditionMet"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <choice doc:name="Choice">
                <when expression="#[(flowVars.conditionMet == true)]">
                    <scripting:component doc:name="Do nothing">
                        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"/>
                    </scripting:component>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <scripting:component doc:name="Continue Loop">
                        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[// Define the collection to loop
def loopCollection = flowVars.nameOfCollectiontoLoop

// Define the condition which needs to be met
def exitCondition = "Some condition to match"

// Define the "conditionMet" variable
def conditionMet = flowVars.conditionMet

// Loop the collection to do what you need
loopCollection.each { row ->
    if (row.identifierName == exitCondition)
    {
        conditionMet = true
    }
    else
    {
        conditionMet = false
        // Continue your processing
    }   
}

return payload]]></scripting:script>
                    </scripting:component>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

Try these and let us know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no component to break the foreach loop. If you only want to process till the success condition, then you could use MEL to execute the foreach on a sublist like this:

```
<foreach collection="#[payload<condition>]" />
 ...
</foreach>
```

You can also use loops in Groovy.

Example. In a payload i have some HashMap -

```
def nap = payload.Result
 for (v in nap)
 {
     if (v.Name == '!!! а папка')
     {
         assert v.Id != null
         flowVars['folderid'] = v.Id
         payload = 'recived Id of folder object is '+v.Id
         break
     }

 }
 return payload
```